# Outlook Redemption won't connect, error pbExchangeProviderPrimaryUserGuid

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, mapi, outlook-redemption

I use Outlook Redemption to sync Outlook calendars with our own planning system.
It connects to an Office365 mailbox that is used as an admin. The admin account then reads planning items from our system and writes them to the calendars of other users that give permission to do so.
The issue is that it sometimes works, but most of the time it does not.

I connect using LogonHostedExchangeMailbox
Then I log the session values. When the issue occurs the session values are:

> 210427 09:13:50 - Current user name="UNKNOWN"
> 210427 09:13:50 - Current user EntryID="00000000812B1FA4BEA310199D6E00DD010F540200000110554E4B4E4F574E00554E4B4E4F574E00554E4B4E4F574E00"
> 210427 09:13:50 - Current user SMTP address=""
> 210427 09:13:50 - Current user address="UNKNOWN"

But sometimes, without me changing anything it works and says:

> 210426 20:34:31 - Current user name="Dylius"
> 210426 20:34:31 - Current user EntryID="00000000DCA740C8C042101AB4B908002B2FE18201000000000000002F6F3D45786368616E67654C6162732F6F753D45786368616E67652041646D696E6973747261746976652047726F7570202846594449424F484632335350444C54292F636E3D526563697069656E74732F636E3D62663562353933643039623734323834613264303465613539316233343863652D64796C69757300"
> 210426 20:34:31 - Current user SMTP address="dylius@flyawaytv.be"
> 210426 20:34:31 - Current user address="/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=bf5b593d09b74284a2d04ea591b348ce-dylius"

Does anyone have an idea as to why it does not work most of the time, while it sometimes does work?

When it does not work, later in my log i get this. It is in dutch but basically means that the Exchange is not available.

> 210427 09:14:37 - Error in IMAPISession::OpenMsgStore(pbExchangeProviderPrimaryUserGuid): MAPI_E_FAILONEPROVIDER
> ulVersion: 0
> Error: Microsoft Exchange is niet beschikbaar. Er is een probleem met het netwerk of er worden onderhoudswerkzaamheden uitgevoerd op de Microsoft Exchange-server.
> Component: Informatiearchief van Microsoft Exchange
> ulLowLevelError: 2147746069
> ulContext: 1318

Comment: Which Outlook version do you have installed on the system? The connection settings are retrieved using `Exchange Autodiscover Service` and a temporary profile is created that uses RPC-over-HTTP (ROH) to connect to the mailbox under Outlook 2013. 
When Outlook 2016 is used, the profile is automatically configured by the MSEMS provider to use either MAPI-over-HTTP or RPC-over-HTTP depending on the Exchange Server version and its settings. Can there be a connection problem?

Comment: Hard to say with MAPI_E_FAILONEPROVIDER - it is a catch-all error "something went wrong". Does it work if Outlook is connecting to the same mailbox at the same time? Does it prompt for the credentials?

Comment: Thanks guys. I am using Outlook 2013. I tried having Outlook open under the admin account during the process but same issue. When Outlook starts it says "loading profile" and then opens without asking for a password. A connection issue will not be the case i suppose since opening Outlook never fails.

Comment: Also, the process is running on an Amazon EC2 instance. Can this be related?

Comment: Any more thoughts about this issue please? Im am stuck...

Comment: I now did the same setup on another computer (non Amazon) . Exact same scenario. It worked once, then each time it failes.

Comment: @MarcCorbeel hello, did you find a solution for this problem ?